# The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateOnly with ASP.NET Core 8 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0, asp.net-core-8, dateonly

Using .NET 8, I've tried passing in various formats of a date to my API endpoint and I can't get past this error. I get a 400 response with the error:

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateOnly

My code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Item>> CreateItem(CreateItemRequest request)
{
    var Item = await _ItemService.CreateItemAsync(request);

    return Ok(Item);
}

public class CreateItemRequest
{
    ...
    public DateOnly CreateDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

JSON request body:

```
{
    ...
    "createDate":"2024-1-7"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model binding with the `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` is available from .NET 7 as mentioned in [Add DateOnly and TimeOnly support to model binding & routing](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34591).

The problem is that your provided date string does not match the [format](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53539). It should be in "yyyy-MM-dd" (ISO 8601) format.

```
{
    "createDate":"2024-01-07"
}
```